# OpenMP Parallel for-loop showing little performance increase

Tags: c, ubuntu, concurrency, parallel-processing, openmp

I am in the process of learning how to use OpenMP in C, and as a HelloWorld exercise I am writing a  program to count primes.  I then parallelise this as follows:

```
int numprimes = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:numprimes)
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (is_prime(i) == true)
        numprimes ++;
}
```

I compile this code using `gcc -g -Wall -fopenmp -o primes primes.c -lm` (`-lm` for the `math.h` functions I am using).  Then I run this code on an `Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz × 2`, and as expected, the performance is better than for a serial program.

The problem, however, comes when I try to run this on a much more powerful machine. (I have also tried to manually set the number of threads to use with `num_threads`, but this did not change anything.)  Counting all the primes up to `10 000 000` gives me the following times (using `time`):

8-core machine:

```
real    0m8.230s
user    0m50.425s
sys     0m0.004s
```

dual-core machine:

```
real    0m10.846s
user    0m17.233s
sys     0m0.004s
```

And this pattern continues for counting more primes, the machine with more cores shows a slight performance increase, but not as much as I would expect for having so many more cores available.  (I would expect 4 times more cores to imply almost 4 times less running time?)

Counting primes up to `50 000 000`:

8-core machine:

```
real    1m29.056s
user    8m11.695s
sys     0m0.017s
```

dual-core machine:

```
real    1m51.119s
user    2m50.519s
sys     0m0.060s
```

If anyone can clarify this for me, it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is my prime-checking function.

```
static int is_prime(int n)
{
  /* handle special cases */
  if      (n == 0) return 0;
  else if (n == 1) return 0;
  else if (n == 2) return 1;

  int i;
  for(i=2;i<=(int)(sqrt((double) n));i++)
    if (n%i==0) return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

Comment: How does your `is_prime` look? If that accesses data shared between the threads, that would cause synchronisation overhead.

Comment: `static int is_prime(int n)` is the header of the function that is called.  I can add the whole function if it would help clarify the problem.  I would think that each thread would automatically call its own function?

Comment: Does the function use any static or (semi-)global data, or does it only use the argument and constants?

Comment: I have added the `is_prime` function, but it does not use any global data.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't cause any synchronisation problems. Might be worth checking the assembly output to make sure that `sqrt(n)` is not recomputed each iteration.

Comment: Your code clearly shows that you should first invest in acquiring knowledge about optimization of sequential code. Parallelizing at the level of where you are is premature: avoid the repetive testing of the special cases in each call, just start your loop at 3. Avoid the repetitive evaluation of `sqrt`. Don't cast the argument to `sqrt`, your compiler will convert it anyhow. Don't use `int`, a signed type, as a base type, `unsigned` or even `size_t` would be more appropriate.

Comment: I copied the `is_prime` function from somewhere else, so I did not write it myself.  But even so, I would want `parallel for` to scale accordingly for more data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This performance is happening because:

1. `is_prime(i)` takes longer the higher `i` gets, and
2. Your OpenMP implementation uses static scheduling by default for `parallel for` constructs without the `schedule` clause, i.e. it chops the for loop into equal sized contiguous chunks.

In other words, the highest-numbered thread is doing all of the hardest operations.

Explicitly selecting a more appropriate scheduling type with the `schedule` clause allows you to divide work among the threads fairly.

This version will divide the work better:

```
int numprimes = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1) reduction(+:numprimes) 
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    if (is_prime(i) == true)
        numprimes ++;
}
```

Information on scheduling syntax is available via [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5aw0hdf(v=vs.80).aspx) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP#Scheduling_clauses).

`schedule(dynamic, 1)` may not be optimal, as [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) notes in his answer. There is a more in-depth discussion of scheduling granularity in this [OpenMP wihtepaper](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/granularity-and-parallel-performance).

Thanks also to [Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366377/jens-gustedt) and [Mahmoud Fayez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223297/mahmoud-fayez) for contributing to this answer.

Comment: My prime-checking function checks all numbers smaller than `sqrt(n)`, and if one divides `n`, then the number is given as not prime.  Thus a larger `i` would indeed lead to more work, but I would think that threads will take work as they finish, thus all threads will receive calls with high `i`s.  Would there be a way to test this?

Comment: @Casper, no, most probably OpenMp divides the indices into equal sized contiguous chunks for each thread. So that highest numbered thread does all the work.

Comment: @JensGustedt, would there be a way to allocate the work fairly to the threads?

Comment: Make an array of the numbers 0 to n-1 in random order. Then run your parallel program on the contents of that array. That will fairly split the work between the threads.

Comment: This would mean creating an array of `50 000 000+` elements, adding significant overhead.  Is this the only way?

Comment: True, if the range is split into equal-sized chunks, the thread getting the chunk with the largest numbers has some more work to do. But it's not a huge difference (compared to the other high chunks) if there are 8 threads. The effect is much larger for 2 threads. So that should get not quite a four-fold speedup over two threads, but less than 3 would be unexpected, @Casper.

Comment: guys you should try to use OpenMP parallel for with scheduling directive manually load balancing the work load among threads is not a bad idea but more code and does not guarantee the best performance.

Comment: The default loop scheduling (i.e. when no `schedule` clause is present) is _implementation dependent_.

Comment: Thanks, I've finally gotten around to testing my solution on the faster machine again, and it seems the `dynamic` scheduling is indeed what does the trick.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the apparently poor scaling of your program is, as @naroom has suggested, the variability in the run time of each call to your `is_prime` function.  The run time does not  simply increase with the value of `i`. Your code shows that the test terminates as soon as the first factor of `i` is found so the longest run times will be for numbers with few (and large) factors, including the prime numbers themselves.

As you've already been told, the default schedule for your parallelisation will parcel out the iterations of the master loop a chunk at a time to the available threads.  For your case of `5*10^7` integers to test and 8 cores to use, the first thread will get the integers `1..6250000` to test, the second will get `6250001..12500000` and so on.  This will lead to a severely unbalanced load across the threads because, of course, the prime numbers are not uniformly distributed.

Rather than using the default scheduling you should experiment with dynamic scheduling.  The following statement tells the run-time to parcel out the iterations of your master loop `m` iterations at a time to the threads in your computation:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic,m)
```

Once a thread has finished its `m` iterations it will be given `m` more to work on.  The trick for you is to find the `sweet spot` for `m`.  Too small and your computation will be dominated by the work that the run time does in parcelling out iterations, too large and your computation will revert to the unbalanced loads that you have already seen.

Take heart though, you will learn some useful lessons about the costs, and benefits, of parallel computation by working through all of this.

Comment: I expect even that schedule(static,1) or similar small chunk sizes would work well, as you just need to round-robin the computations here.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code need to use dynamic so the threads each can consume different number of iterations as your iterations have different work load so the current code is balanced which won't help in your case try this out please:

```
int numprimes = 0;
#pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:numprimes) schedule(dynamic,1)
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    if (is_prime(i) == true)
    ++numprimes;
}
```

Comment: you need to understand the difference between the different scheduling types and which one to use according to the problem. the default is static which means each thread executes the same number of iterations. Dynamic means the thread that is free will execute 1 or more iterations till the other busy threads are free to execute more iterations too.

Comment: A chunk size of `1` is likely to result in the computation time being dominated by the time spent managing the iterations; `(dynamic,1)` means that each thread will compute 1 iteration before requesting more work.  This approach will give the best load balance but impose too much parallel overhead.

Comment: You are right, but if the overhead is 1ms and the benefit is balancing the load of iterations that vary from 1ms to 1s then I would encourage using dynamic with size of 1.