# OpenMP: decide if they are prime numbers

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Note that this is a thinking-based question.
The given code tries to test whether numbers up to a certain range (10,000,000) are prime or not.

```
bool test_prime(int x){
   if (x == 0)
      return false;
   int lim = (int) sqrt((double) x);
   for (int i = 2; i <= lim; i++) {
      if (x % i == 0)
          return false;
   }
   return true;
}

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int t = 0; t < nthreads; t++) {
    tf(t, nthreads, xmax, isprime);
}
```

There are two types of thread functions `tf`:

```
void thread_run_interleave(int t, int nthreads, int xmax, bool *isprime) {
    for (int x = t; x <= xmax; x += nthreads) {
        isprime[x] = test_prime(x);
    }
}

void thread_run_chunk(int t, int nthreads, int xmax, bool *isprime) {
    int npt = (xmax + nthreads - 1)/nthreads;
    int xstart = npt*t;
    int xlast = t == nthreads-1 ? xmax : xstart + npt - 1;
    for (int x = xstart; x <= xlast; x++) {
        isprime[x] = test_prime(x);
    }
}
```

The speedups are given below:

1. 2 threads: interleave 1.04, chunk 1.62
2. 3 threads: interleave 1.93, chunk 2.17
3. 4 threads: interleave 1.92, chunk 2.74
4. 5 threads: interleave 3.53, chunk 3.08
5. 6 threads: interleave 1.93, chunk 3.86

The first question asks to explain `thread_run_interleave`'s speedups. (Note: answering this question requires
thinking about the behavior of `test_prime` . e.g., when must it do very little work?)

- Why is there no speedup using 2 threads?
- Why isn’t the speedup monotonic with respect to the number of threads? (Hint: note
  behavior at 4 and 6 threads.)

I honestly don't know the reason for this. I know `test_prime` does little work when the input `x` is small, and it does lots of work for large values.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] for your question and add a detailed hardware description as well as information on how you compile the code.

Comment: ok i just figured out the 2 thread reason. thread 0 gets all the even numbers, hence none of them are prime and they are divisible by 2 and exit the test_prime quickly. thread 1 on the other hand will have to test longer since it has all the prime numbers. This workload imbalance causes 1 thread to run the majority of the work, so it is close to serial in terms of speed.

Comment: @Zulan this is actually a written homework question, so no codes.

Comment: @KcAble you can write answer yourself and accept it.

Comment: There are several Qs and As around here which address the matters raised in this question.  See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463046

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the hardware you are testing on, you might run into false sharing in the function `thread_run_interleave`, since you are writing to `isprime[x]` and in each thread the value `x` might be similar (depending on how these threads will be scheduled on cpu). That could explain the slowdown when using more threads.

This could be fixed by processing a small chunk of conescutive numbers in each thread.
Suppose your cache line is 64B wide, then you would process 64/sizeof(bool) consecutive numbers in each thread and then move `x` by (64/sizeof(bool))*nthreads (assuming `isprime` is an array of bools).